# Laravel Passport - How to login via webapp?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

I've set up a central app (let's call this `maindomain.com`), where I've setup Passport. This site will be where users register to gain access to all other apps I create.

To test it out, I've followed [Matt Stauffer's blog post](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-laravel-passport) to create a client app that will use the user data stored on `maindomain.com`, let's call this `app1.com`.

I can confirm that my callback and whatnot work fine. When you go to `app1.com/login` (as per my route) it redirects to `maindomain.com` and allows you to authorise `app1.com` to use your login details - beautiful.

As per Matt's post, right now it prints the token to the screen. I need to change this so that it saves to the database - I assume I should just create a column on my user's table and store it there?

I've tested the token and can access the API routes using Postman. However, because at the moment I'm creating web apps that all need to use this centralised user system, I'm not sure how I can use a login form to authorise users and allow them access to their dashboard.

If user's are logging into `app1.com` do I send a POST request to `maindomain.com`? Isn't that going to be a problem with CSRF? I've read the documentation but as this is my first venture into `Oauth2` I am pretty confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your login form to reside on app1.com, your only choice is Password Grant flow - app1.com will get user credentials and make a POST request to oauth/tokens on maindomain.com trying to get an access token. This POST request may happen in front-end or in back-end (more secure - client password will be hidden), that's up to you.

Otherwise, it sounds like your Authorization Code flow is already up and running. You could just keep redirecting users to maindomain.com (Facebook and most other OAuth2 providers choose this way), use the login form *there*, and then redirect back and fetch access token based on authorization code. Save that code in your app1.com database and allow users to access dashboard using that. When it expires - start the flow again.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. And when a user is logged in, and I need to use them on app1.com - how do i check they are authenticated?

Comment: If user has a valid (not expired) access token in the session data - user is authenticated

Comment: So in Laravel, can I still access the user using something like `Auth::user()->id` or will it no longer work that way? I'll be storing information in the app1.com's database that would be unique to each user (orders etc.). I understand the principle of Passport, I'm just not using JS to consume the API on the web apps so I dont 100% get *how* to use the access tokens

Comment: Laravel where - on app1.com? To use Auth there, you would need to write your own auth guard but I don't see any problems. Try searching on GitHub - perhaps there are some packages already. Or maybe you can borrow the auth guard from Laravel Passport even

Comment: Alright I'll try and work it all out. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try watching this video by Taylor (the creator of laravel) to get going:

https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13

I created repos for both project and confirmed them working as they should:

API Server:
https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-passport

API Consumer:
https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-consumer

Try making protected API end-points in the routing file `api.php` and use token scopes if needed to further protect the API endpoints :)

Comment: As my question says, i already have it working. Just not how i want it to

Comment: I mean it is a valid answer and I understand, but I've watched Taylor's vid (which btw, is pretty much the video version of Matt's blog post). But it doesn't explain how to authenticate and using forms or how to access the user's data etc.

Comment: Php artisan make:auth it's that simple to make the auth.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding what i'm saying

Comment: make:auth makes the auth scaffold yes, but like i've said, the documentation, blog post or videos *don't* say how you authenticate a request inside a web app using a form.

Comment: I have the passport app set up, i have consumer clients set up - i cannot find any useful information on how to login from consumer clients and use user data on the web app